# Text Split cognitive skill not visible in UI

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I am adding Azure Search and trying to add skills for content enrichment.

I can see the `Key Phrase Extraction` and the `Language Detection` [predefined skills](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-predefined-skills) but not the `Text Split` skill on the screen. Is there a reason why `Text Split` skill is not visible? Or is it something that can only be added via API?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capabilities exposed throught the portal focus on core scenarios that customers want to perform so they do not include text splitting.  If you want to split your text, you should do it by creating your own skillset programatically through the API, that will allow you to define the language and the size of a page.